# What is the difference between Employment card and Blue card of Czech Republic ?

Tags: eu-citizens, blue-card, czech-republic

Need to travel to Prague for employment. 
I'm very confused about whether I should I apply for a blue card or an Employment card

Comment: How long will you be staying?

Answer (score 3):

The Czech Ministry of the Interior [gives the following definition](http://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/eu-blue-cards.aspx?q=Y2hudW09MQ%3D%3D) for the Blue Card (Modrá karta):

> An EU Blue Card is a new residential status designed for a long-term
>   stay involving the performance of a highly skilled job (§ 42i of the
>   Act on the Residence of Foreign Nationals). An EU Blue Card entitles a
>   foreign national to stay and perform a job, i.e. the foreign national
>   does not need a separate work permit.
>
> Duly completed university education or higher vocational education,
>   the duration of which was at least 3 years, is deemed to be a high
>   level of skills.

And [here is the definition](http://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/employee-card-682810.aspx) for the Employee Card (Zaměstnanecká karta):

> An employee card is a new type of permit for long-time residence in
>   the territory of the Czech Republic (CR) where the purpose of the
>   foreign national’ stay (longer than 3 months) is employment. A foreign
>   national who has an employee card is entitled:
>
> - to reside in the territory of the CR and, at the same time,
> - to work in the job for which the employee card was issued, or
> - to work in the job for which the Department for Asylum and Migration
>     Policy of the Ministry of the Interior granted consent (in connection
>     with changing employer, changing job, taking up employment with an
>     additional employer or in an additional job).

The advantage of the Blue Card is that you can switch jobs without approval from the Department of the Interior. The condition for it is that you must be employed in a high-skilled job. If you're eligible for the Blue Card, you should definitely apply for one.